# Validation Between Date In Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have object

```
var items = [
[{
    id: 1
    start: "2015-03-01 21:50:00",
    end: "2015-03-01 21:51:00"
}],
[{
    id: 2
    start: "2015-03-01 21:50:06",
    end: "2015-03-01 21:52:00"
}],
[{
    id: 3
    start: "2015-03-01 21:50:08",
    end: "2015-03-01 21:51:40"
}],
[{
    id: 4
    start: "2015-03-01 21:50:16",
    end: "2015-03-01 21:52:50"
}],
[{
    id: 5
    start: "2015-03-01 21:50:30",
    end: "2015-03-01 21:54:50"
}],
[{
    id: 6
    start: "2015-03-02 21:50:59",
    end: "2015-03-01 21:54:08"
  }]
];
```

Same like I have lacks of rows, I have to calculate how many have records in 1 minutes with start time and end_time parameters.

How can I achieve this with javascript and mongodb.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: no duplication check count we require only..

Comment: Is that a collection? Your question is a bit unclear on the mongodb part, if you want to do this in mongodb, how is your document schema defined?

Comment: yes its collection. if its possible to get result with mongo its good.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to compare the two fields, get the difference in minutes for start and end fields. You could either do this in two ways.

The first approach would be to use the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator in your [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) query. Suppose your collection `items` is made up of these documents:

```
db.items.insert([
{
    _id: 1,
    start: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:50:00"),
    end: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:51:00")
},
{
    _id: 2,
    start: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:50:06"),
    end: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:52:00")
},
{
    _id: 3,
    start: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:50:08"),
    end: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:51:40")
},
{
    _id: 4,
    start: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:50:16"),
    end: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:52:50")
},
{
    _id: 5,
    start: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:50:30"),
    end: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:54:50")
},
{
    _id: 6,
    start: ISODate("2015-03-02 21:50:59"),
    end: ISODate("2015-03-01 21:54:08")
 }
])
```

using the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator to get those documents with a one minute duration between start and end dates (assuming those times are on the same day), the query:

```
db.items.find({"$where": "this.end.getMinutes() - this.start.getMinutes() == 1"});

returns

/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "start" : ISODate("2015-03-01T21:50:00.000Z"),
    "end" : ISODate("2015-03-01T21:51:00.000Z")
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "start" : ISODate("2015-03-01T21:50:08.000Z"),
    "end" : ISODate("2015-03-01T21:51:40.000Z")
}
```

However, there are some points worth considering when using the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator. From the docs:

> $where evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes.
>   Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query
>   using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., $gt, $in). In general, you
>   should use $where only when you can’t express your query using another
>   operator. If you must use $where, try to include at least one other
>   standard query operator to filter the result set. Using $where alone
>   requires a table scan.

The second approach would be to use MongoDB's **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**. Your pipeline would typically be as follows:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {"_id": "$_id",
            "start_year": { "$year": "$start" },
            "start_month": { "$month": "$start" },
            "start_day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$start" },
            "start_hour": { "$hour": "$start" },
            "start_minutes": { "$minute": "$start" },
            "end_year": { "$year": "$end" },
            "end_month": { "$month": "$end" },
            "end_day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$end" },
            "end_hour": { "$hour": "$end" },
            "end_minutes": { "$minute": "$end" }},
            "data": {
                "$addToSet": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "isMinuteDuration": {
                "$eq": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$_id.end_minutes", "$_id.start_minutes" ] },
                    1                   
                ]
            },            
            "data": 1,
            "_id": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "isMinuteDuration": true
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$data"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$data._id",
            "start": "$data.start",
            "end": "$data.end"
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "start" : ISODate("2015-03-01T21:50:08.000Z"),
            "end" : ISODate("2015-03-01T21:51:40.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "start" : ISODate("2015-03-01T21:50:00.000Z"),
            "end" : ISODate("2015-03-01T21:51:00.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```